# Not able to save .xlsx file as PDF in the sharepoint list through save a copy in Excel.

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I am trying to save a .xlsx file as the pdf file in the sharepoint list by the desktop excel. Each time I am receiving the same error described below.

Error: - Document not saved. The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the excel file was in Preview Mode, modify it to edit mode.

And check if you already open this file, close another file and save it again.